# Object Oriented Programming in PHP not clear

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue in understanding Object Oriented Programming in `PHP`. I believe if i can pass through this a lot of doors would be opened for me. I already know how to write in line `php`. I have taking a course but i can't still seem to wrap my head around this yet. But here is what i don't understand.

Say i create a `php class` with `function`s in it as below.

**Database.php**

```
<?php

/*Contains DB Connect function and other query functions that has to do with database*/

class Database 
{
    //Database conn properties

    private $host   = 'localhost';
    private $user   = 'root';
    private $pass   = 'password';
    private $dbname = 'rtmdb';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        //Function for database connection
        //Set DSN

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $this->host . ';dbname'. $this->dbname;

        //Set Options include persistent connection

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        //Create new PDO Instance

        try
        { 
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        //@param function for executing insert, select, update

        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

        if(!$this->stmt)
        {
            echo $this->dbh->lastErrorMsg();
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) 
    {
        if(is_null($type))
        {
            switch(true)
            {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                    default;
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function lastInsertId() 
    {
        $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function resultset()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSCO);
    }

}
```

From my understanding on the course i took, I know i can make use of these `function`s as below

```
<?php
/*Working With Database*/
/*PHP Data Objects (PDO)*/

require 'classes/Database.php';

$database = new Database;



$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $title = $post['title'];
    $body = $post['body'];

    $database->query('INSERT INTO post (title, body) VALUES(:title, :body)');
    $database->bind(':title', $title);
    $database->bind(':body', $body);
    $database->execute();

    if($database->lastInsertId()) {
        echo '<p>Post Added</p>';
    }
}

$database->query('SELECT * FROM post');
// $database->bind(':id', 1);
$rows = $database->resultset();

?>

<h1>Add Post</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <lable>Post Totle</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Add a Title"><br><br>
    <label>Post Body</label>
   <textarea name="body"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<h1>Posts</h1>
<div>
<?php foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
<div>
    <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['body'];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

So my question here is, Is it possible to convert the `php` in the `html` file into another `class` and `methods` or `function`s? If so how? Understanding this would help me a lot in my understanding of Object Oriented Programming in `PHP`.

Thanks

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used the mysqli tag, when there's clearly PDO syntax here. Edit: Tadman removed it and added the relevant tag.

Comment: you also made a typo here `FETCH_ASSCO`

Comment: What you have here is a sort of confusion of PHP, HTML, and SQL all cluttered into one file. Modern web development makes extensive use of the [Model-View-Controller Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) to simplify this and make it a lot more clear where certain kinds of code goes. What you have here, while reinventing the wheel, should work if you fix some of the minor problems. The concern I have is that slamming together an application out of randomly linked `.php` files isn't sustainable. You need to separate your concerns or they'll end up all inter-mixed.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: If you're learning OOP, ignore this example from wherever you saw it, if OOP is hard to understand, understanding an ORM is useless until you can reed the benefit of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking of is a "view" layer.

This layer is typically not a class itself, it's usually just a PHP file with access to functions to help with view related things - like rounding numbers or capitalizing words, etc.

You could take a stab at writing your own template library or use an existing engine like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/).